# Fast.com Settings

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, performance, internet-speed

Does anyone know how Fast.com picks the settings they use to measure for upload and download speed? For example, my latest test picked 330MB for download and 30 MB for upload. Clicking into the settings didn't seem to give a chance to edit this directly

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there is no option to change the size of the file that is downloaded or uploaded then it cannot be configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set min and max test duration. Exact time will be as long as necessary to determine the speed reliably, but no longer than max. How much data will be downloaded depends on your connection's speed - faster connections will download more data over the same time.